# Using onAuthStateChanged to query user data that includes an array from Firebase causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My current environment is ReactJS 18.2.0 with Firebase running on 10.

The current issue I'm running into is using onAuthStateChanged to query data about the user whenever they load or login into the page.

Here's the code snippet example from a custom Service created for handling Firebase Auth.

all sets are part of a Context which are all useStates.

```js
const subscribeToAuthChanges = (
  handleAuthChange,
  setLoadingState,
  setUserRole,
  setEmail,
  setFirstName,
  setIsActive,
  setLastName,
  setLocation,
  setUserID
) => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      handleAuthChange(user);

      FirebaseFirestoreService.getUserData(user.uid).then((data) => {
        setUserID(user.uid);
        setUserRole(data.role);
        setEmail(data.email);
        setFirstName(data.firstName);
        setIsActive(data.isActive);
        setLastName(data.lastName);
        setLocation(data.location);
      });
      setLoadingState(false);
    } else {
      setLoadingState(false);
    }
  });
};
```

FirebaseFirestoreService.getUserData() Function

```js
const getUserData = async (id) => {
  const docRef = doc(db, "users", id);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    return docSnap.data();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

This is not supposed to be run in a useEffect a Context was created to handle this.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FirebaseAuthService from "../Services/FirebaseAuthService";

const FirebaseAuth = React.createContext({
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  role: "",
  email: "",
  firstName: "",
  isActive: false,
  lastName: "",
  location: "",
  userID: "",
});

export const FirebaseAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState("");

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  FirebaseAuthService.subscribeToAuthChanges(
    setUser,
    setLoading,
    setRole,
    setEmail,
    setFirstName,
    setIsActive,
    setLastName,
    setLocation,
    setUserID
  );

  return (
    <FirebaseAuth.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        loading,
        role,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        isActive,
        location,
        userID,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FirebaseAuth.Provider>
  );
};

export default FirebaseAuth;
```

In this example, I'm missing one of my set functions, which is querying an array of strings. however, querying the array of string causes onAuthStateChanged() to continue looping creating reads to Firebase over and over.

Is there a way to read an array without running into this issue?

I've tried looping through the array to avoid running into this issue, however, querying it in any way causes Firebase to be POST Requested over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your runs in a loop because on you havent set the onAuthStateChanged() in a side effect, try the following

```js
const FirebaseAuth = React.createContext({
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  role: '',
  email: '',
  firstName: '',
  isActive: false,
  lastName: '',
  location: '',
  userID: '',
});

export const FirebaseAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [role, setRole] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        FirebaseFirestoreService.getUserData(user.uid).then((data) => {
          setUserID(user.uid);
          setUserRole(data.role);
          setEmail(data.email);
          setFirstName(data.firstName);
          setIsActive(data.isActive);
          setLastName(data.lastName);
          setLocation(data.location);
        });
        setLoadingState(false);
      } else {
        setLoadingState(false);
      }
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <FirebaseAuth.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        loading,
        role,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        isActive,
        location,
        userID,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FirebaseAuth.Provider>
  );
};

export default FirebaseAuth;
```

Here is the reason, whenever the state of your component changes , another onAuthStateChange listener is attached to your component which changes the state of the component and this falls into a loop.
Remember this side effect should only run once when the component is mounted, it should not have a dependecy array, otherwise more than one listeners will be attached to component.

Comment: Ahmer, This unfortunately does not fix my issue. A context was created to call onAuthStateChanged so there would be direct access across all components for this.

Comment: Edited the code, try it

Comment: OnAuthStateChanged shouldn't be leaving the React Service, however, with that modification this did work.